# Excel VBA Loop: search in several folders for inserting a foto

Tags: excel, vba, image, loops, if-statement

Good afternoon,
I am creating a macro in an excel file.
I am writing a bunch of articles references numbers in a excel sheet, and I am looking to insert the fotos of those articles in the cell next to, through a macro. But I need to look for those fotos in several folders: "year 2024, year 2023, year 2022..."

I know how to look for those fotos in a single folder, but not to write like a loop "if in the folder 2024 the foto does not exist, then look in folder 2023, and if not, then look in the folder 2022", and so on". I am trying to specify from which year till which other year should I look for through an "Input box".

I wrote this.

```
Sub Insert_fotos()
   Dim str_FolderPath As String
   Dim rng_ref As Range
   Dim foto As Object
   Dim str_folder_i As String
   
   str_FolderPath = "K:\ADMINISTRACION_COMPRAS\06_Admon_NF\02.Contratos"
   rng_ref = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
   str_folder_i = InputBox("Ano de inicio de la busqueda", title:="Ano inicio", Default:="2018, 2019, 2020...")
   
   On Error Resume Next
   ' ---------------------------Delete fotos----------------------------------------------------
   For Each foto In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      foto.Delete
   Next foto
   ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Select
   
   Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).value = ""
      ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (str_FolderPath & "\Ano " & str_folder_i & "\" & rng_ref.value & "Foto " & rng_ref.value & ".jpg")
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop
   
   Range("B4").Select
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I tried this but it only looks in one single folder. I think it could work a "For i = / Next i loop"

Comment: I suggest looking into the `FileSystemObject` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object). With this you can loop over folder and file collections (and find specific files that way).

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Pictures From Folder to Excel

```vb
Sub UpdatePhotos()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PICTURES_PATH As String _
        = "K:\ADMINISTRACION_COMPRAS\06_Admon_NF\02.Contratos"
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "D4"
    Const PICTURE_COLUMN As String = "E"
    Const FILE_EXTENSION As String = "jpg"
    Const iPROMPT As String = "Input a range of years"
    Const iTITLE As String = "Period Input"
    Const iDEFAULT As String = "2018-2030"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the range containing the file names.
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet """ & ws.Name & """.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Get the input.
    
    Dim Period As String: Period = InputBox(iPROMPT, iTITLE, Default:=iDEFAULT)
    
    If Len(Period) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation  ' or supplied nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Determine the first and second year.
    
    Dim PeriodYears() As String: PeriodYears = Split(Period, "-")
    Dim yValue: yValue = PeriodYears(0)
    Dim yStep As Long: yStep = 1
    
    Dim FirstYear As Long, SecondYear As Long, IsPeriodValid As Boolean
     
    If IsNumeric(yValue) Then
        FirstYear = yValue
        If UBound(PeriodYears) = 0 Then
            SecondYear = FirstYear
        Else
            yValue = PeriodYears(1)
            If IsNumeric(yValue) Then
                SecondYear = yValue
            End If
        End If
        If SecondYear < FirstYear Then yStep = -1
        IsPeriodValid = True
    End If
        
    If Not IsPeriodValid Then
        MsgBox "The input """ & Period & """ is invalid.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Write all the folder paths to the 'keys' of a dictionary and each file
    ' in the folder to a collection held in the corresponding 'item'.
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
    Dim fsoFile As Object, y As Long, FolderPath As String, fExt As String
    
    For y = FirstYear To SecondYear Step yStep
        FolderPath = fso.BuildPath(PICTURES_PATH, y)
        If fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
            Set dict(FolderPath) = New Collection
            For Each fsoFile In fso.Getfolder(FolderPath).Files
                fExt = fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile)
                If StrComp(fExt, FILE_EXTENSION, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    dict(FolderPath).Add fsoFile.Name
                End If
            Next fsoFile
        End If
    Next y
            
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching folders found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Delete all existing pictures.
    
    ws.Pictures.Delete
    
    ' Copy the new pictures.
    
    Dim cell As Range, pic As Picture, Key, Item, IsPictureFound As Boolean
    Dim BaseName As String, fname As String, FilePath As String
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        BaseName = CStr(cell.Value)
        If Len(BaseName) > 0 Then
            fname = BaseName & "." & FILE_EXTENSION
            For Each Key In dict.Keys
                For Each Item In dict(Key)
                    If StrComp(fname, Item, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        FilePath = fso.BuildPath(Key, Item)
                        ' Insert picture.
                        ' (Not sure if there is a better way)
                        Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(FilePath)
                        With cell.EntireRow.Columns(PICTURE_COLUMN)
                            pic.Top = .Top
                            pic.Left = .Left
                        End With
                        IsPictureFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next Item
                If IsPictureFound Then
                    IsPictureFound = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Key
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Inform.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Photos updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```